# Oracle Sequence starting with 2 instead of 1

Tags: oracle, sequence, oracle11g

**Unexpected behavior:**

I am encountering strange behavior of Oracle sequences with 11g (works with 10g):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test_sequence START WITH 1;
CREATE TABLE test_table ( val INT );

INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ( test_sequence.NEXTVAL );
```

Even though the sequence starts with **1**, the first value inserted is **2**:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table;

       VAL
----------
         2
```

---

**Expected behavior:**

Selecting `NEXTVAL` without the insert works as expected:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test_sequence_2 START WITH 1;

SELECT test_sequence_2.NEXTVAL FROM dual

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1
```

---

**Question:**

Can anyone reproduce this using Oracle 11g? Is this a known issue?

I'm using
`Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`.

Comment: It returns `1` on my `Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.6.0 - 64bit Production`

Comment: @Quassnoi: This seems to be a "feature" of `11.2` (see Jeffrey's answer). Thanks for testing!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is [documented in the 11.2 SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF55572) where it says,

> If you attempt to insert a sequence value into a table that uses deferred segment creation, the first value that the sequence returns will be skipped.

See the link in Jeffrey Kemp's answer for a My Oracle Support (Metalink) note and a workaround.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say the cause is this "undocumented feature".  See My Oracle Support Document ID 1273858.1 (which is unfortunately behind a paywall and cannot be copied here).

Try it without deferred segment creation and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce on 11G, i.e. the table contains a 1 after following your steps.

However, it is debatable whether this should be considered an "issue", because sequences are never guaranteed to be gap-free.  What START WITH guarantees is that the sequence will never return a value **lower** than the specified starting value - e.g. to avoid conflicts with existing data.  I do agree however that what you are seeing is surprising and I would be interested to know the reason!

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SQ_SEQUENCE_NAME
    INCREMENT BY 1
    START WITH 1
    MINVALUE 0  -- This will ensure start at 1!
    MAXVALUE 99
    NOCYCLE
    NOCACHE
    ORDER;
```

Comment: Thanks god for this answer, impossible to visualize Jeffrey Kemp post if not on a company