# sequence.nextval in oracle seems to increment twice

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to understand how nextval increments a sequence:
in the following it seems that inside an INSERT INTO ...VALUES statement,
nextval will increment twice the sequence. But only for the first such statement.
I did not understand the reason for this behaviour in the [ORACLE manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns002.htm)

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(a INT);
CREATE SEQUENCE seqa START WITH 10;
CREATE SEQUENCE seqb START WITH 10;

INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(seqb.NEXTVAL);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(seqb.NEXTVAL);
SELECT * FROM test_table;
```

Resulting test_table:

```
A
-----
11
12
```

whereas:

```
SELECT seqa.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; -- returns 10
```

Comment: Are you seeing [this deferred segment creation behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4153807/266304)? Which is [documented here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314)?

Comment: Oh yes, I had missed the duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, that link is dead; it's [documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF55572) (at the moment!).

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't happen for me (on Oracle 12C):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test_table(a INT);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE seqa START WITH 10;

Sequence created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE seqb START WITH 10;

Sequence created.

SQL> INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(seqb.NEXTVAL);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(seqb.NEXTVAL);

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM test_table;

         A
----------
        10
        11
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE** I didn't realize the question has 11g tag, my answer is specific to 12c. Might be useful to folks who have upgraded or would upgrade to 12c.

In addition to @Tony's answer, on `Oracle 12c` you won't need an explicit `sequence`. Make use of `IDENTITY COLUMNS` introduced in version `12.1.`

For example,

```
    SQL> CREATE TABLE new_identity_table
      2    (
      3      ID   NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
      4      text VARCHAR2(50)
      5    );

    Table created.

    SQL>
    SQL> INSERT
      2  INTO new_identity_table
      3    (
      4      text
      5    )
      6    VALUES
      7    (
      8      'This table has an identity column'
      9    );

    1 row created.

    SQL> column text format A40;
    SQL>
    SQL> select * from new_identity_table;

            ID TEXT
    ---------- ----------------------------------------
             1 This table has an identity column

    SQL>

Oracle creates a `sequence` to populate the `identity column`. You can find it named as `ISEQ$$`

    SQL> select sequence_name, min_value, max_value, increment_by from user_sequences;

    SEQUENCE_NAME         MIN_VALUE  MAX_VALUE                     INCREMENT_BY
    -------------------- ---------- ----------------------------   ------------
    ISEQ$$_93199                  1 9999999999999999999999999999   1

    SQL>

More more information about the identity columns, use the `ALL_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS` view.

    SQL> SELECT table_name,
      2         column_name,
      3         generation_type,
      4         identity_options
      5  FROM   all_tab_identity_cols
      6  WHERE  owner = 'LALIT'
      7  ORDER BY 1, 2;

    TABLE_NAME           COLUMN_NAME     GENERATION IDENTITY_OPTIONS
    -------------------- --------------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
    NEW_IDENTITY_TABLE   ID              ALWAYS     START WITH: 1, INCREMENT BY: 1, MAX_VALUE: 9999999
                                                    999999999999999999999, MIN_VALUE: 1, CYCLE_FLAG: N
                                                    , CACHE_SIZE: 20, ORDER_FLAG: N


    SQL>
```

Comment: The question is tagged 11g though.

Comment: Ah, I completely missed to see it, got carried away with @Tony's answer. Thanks Alex. I will add a note to my answer.